# how to apply a function (matrix -> scalar) to 3 dim a numpy array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have 3 dimensional numpy array `a`, for example as below:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randn(3, 3, 3)
```

How can I apply (matrix->scalar)-type function to `a`? More specifically, I want to do an equivalent thing as below in a more computationally efficient way:

```py
[np.linalg.det(e) for e in a]
```

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/tutorials_index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.linalg.det(a)` seems to work just fine and has significantly better runtime:

```
a = np.random.rand(100,3,3)

%timeit -n 100 [np.linalg.det(e) for e in a]
626 µs ± 26.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit -n 100 np.linalg.det(a)
33.9 µs ± 7.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```